# How to get corners of shapes in threejs

Tags: three.js, geometry, drawing

I am developing a shape drawing tool in threejs. I have drawn line, square, circle, rectangle, triangle, ellipse etc. on mouse down + drag successfully. Now i want editing of these shapes, such as scale, move and rotate. How do I get the corners and put points at corners where user can mouse+drag to scale , move points etc.

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
        if(edit) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( selectedObject ) {
                selectedObject.material.color.set( '#49BFFE' );
                selectedObject = null;
            }
            var intersects = getIntersects( event );
            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                var res = intersects.filter( function ( res ) {
                    return res && res.object;
                } )[ 0 ];
                if ( res && res.object ) {
                    selectedObject = res.object;
                    selectedObject.material.color.set( '#f00' );
                    console.log(selectedObject)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code to create shapes is as follows:

```
this.onMouseDown = function( relative ) {
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x49BFFE, wireframe: false });
        square = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scope.group.add(square);
    }

    this.onDrag = function( clientX, clientY ) {
        var scale = Math.abs(clientX) + Math.abs(clientY);
        if(scale == 0) scale = scale + 0.1;
        square.scale.set(scale, scale, 0.1);
    }
```

Comment: Look for `Mesh.boundingBox`. You should be able to extrapolate the corners of this box to represent your object.

Comment: It seems to make sense to have a logical representation in form of a class for your objects. The class could contain the visual representation (the mesh) and update it according to your edits. Especially for circles and ellipses, a different logical representation than for polygons seems inevitable.

Comment: console.log(selectedObject.geometry); gives; boundingBox: null,
boundingSphere: nb {center: n, radius: 0.7071067811865476}; and .computeBoundingSphere() does not work

Comment: You might take a look at the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) the source for which is [in the repo](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/editor). Also `const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(someNode);` will return a box that contains all other objects below `someNode`